# X has 7 features per sample; expecting 18282

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm trying to make a textclassification model with sklearn. I'm quite new to python and also sklearn. I already made the model with some training data and saved the model. But there's an error when I try to reuse the model in an another python program/file.

I already looked in some similar problems here on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find a solution for me.

I made some comments, so you can read the code more easily.

```
...
# load the dataset
data = codecs.open('C:/Users/baran/PycharmProjects/test/resource/CorpusMitLabelsPlusSonstige.txt', encoding='utf8',
               errors='ignore').read ()

# seperate lables from text
labels, texts = [], []
for i, line in enumerate(data.split("\n")):
    content = line.split()
    labels.append(content[0])
    texts.append(" ".join(content[1:]))

# create a dataframe using texts and lables
trainDF = pandas.DataFrame()
trainDF['text'] = texts
trainDF['label'] = labels

# split the dataset into training and validation datasets
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(trainDF['text'], trainDF['label'])

# label encode the target variable
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
train_y = encoder.fit_transform(train_y)
valid_y = encoder.fit_transform(valid_y)

# create a count vectorizer object
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
count_vect.fit(trainDF['text'])

# transform the training and validation data using count vectorizer object
xtrain_count = count_vect.transform(train_x)
xvalid_count = count_vect.transform(valid_x)
...
```

And since I was training with different methods to evaluate which was better I made a train_model method.

```
...
def train_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid, is_neural_net=False, is_not_tfid=False,
            correct_model=False):
    # fit the training dataset on the classifier
    ...
    elif correct_model:
        classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)
        pkl_filename = "C:/Users/baran/PycharmProjects/test/resources/pickle_model.pkl"
        with open(pkl_filename, 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(classifier, file)
        # with open(pkl_filename, 'rb') as file:
        #     pickle_model = pickle.load(file)
        # joblib.dump(classifier, "C:/Users/baran/PycharmProjects/test/resources/model.pkl")
        # loaded_model = joblib.load("C:/Users/baran/PycharmProjects/test/resources/model.pkl")
        # result = loaded_model.score(feat)
        # print(pickle_model.predict(feature_vector_valid))
    ...
    # predict the labels on validation dataset
    predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)
    ...
    return metrics.accuracy_score(valid_y, predictions)
...
```

This is the "correct_model":

```
...
# Linear Classifier on Count Vectors
accuracy = train_model(linear_model.LogisticRegression(), xtrain_count, train_y, xvalid_count, correct_model=True)
print("LR, Count Vectors: ", accuracy)
...
```

This model gives me something around 80% accuracy on the validation data.

So this is my test file where I wanted to test, if I can load and reuse the model:

```
...
texts = []
texts.append("Der Bus hat nicht an der Haltestelle gehalten")

# create a dataframe using texts and lables
trainDF = pandas.DataFrame()
trainDF['text'] = texts

# create a count vectorizer object
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
count_vect.fit(trainDF['text'])

# transform the training and validation data using count vectorizer object
test_data = count_vect.transform(trainDF['text'])

# load the model
pkl_filename = "C:/Users/baran/PycharmProjects/test/resources/pickle_model.pkl"
with open(pkl_filename, 'rb') as file:
    pickle_model = pickle.load(file)

#reuse the model
test_load = joblib.load("C:/Users/baran/PycharmProjects/test/model.pkl")
print(test_load.predict(test_data))
...
```

Then I get this error:

```
...
ValueError: X has 7 features per sample; expecting 18282
```

What I expected is, that it will give me "3" as a result which is the encoding for a specific label. These predictions works in the same file where I also train the model, but somehow I can not use new validation data.

I think I made some mistake when fitting and or transforming the data.

Comment: You need to make the exactly same transformations in the new data in order to reuse the model. For instance, you need to use the same `CountVectorizer` you had already used to train the model. So you are only going to `transform` the new data using the `count_vect` you already have. Probably, you want to dump the `CountVectorizer` as well, to be able to use it later.

Comment: But I also need to dump the classifier right? Or can I dump both, the CountVectorizer and the classifier, which in this case is the linear_model.LogisticRegression(). Sorry for asking that. This is my first time using sklearn.

Comment: Dump both of them in separetes pkl. Then, to predict new values you should load both, and use the `CountVectorizer` to `transform` and the model to `predict`.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. That makes total sense. I'll try it later and let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: Hi @vmouffron it's working perfectly. I'm really gratefull for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped!